# How to post in the same message from discord bot command with python

Tags: python

How to post in the same message from discord bot command with python

I am programming a discord bot something simple but I have a small problem and it is that I need to post ..

This:

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5W3O.png

In the same message and I don't know how to do it, the code I'm using adds it to me separately and I would like to be able to do it in the same message

The code I'm using is the following:

code:

````
headers = {'Authorization': 'Client-ID ',}
    params = {'image': base64.b64encode(open('cosmetico.png', 'rb').read())}
    r = requests.post(f'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', headers=headers, data=params)
    
    data = r.json()
    for i in data["data"]:
        await ctx.send(f"Link directo:\n```{i['link']}```")
        await ctx.send(f"BBCode(Para foros):\n```[img]{i['link']}[/img]```")
````

Thank you very much in advance!

Could someone help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use a \n character to create a new line, and use the same ctx#send() method.

````
headers = {'Authorization': 'Client-ID ',}
    params = {'image': base64.b64encode(open('cosmetico.png', 'rb').read())}
    r = requests.post(f'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', headers=headers, data=params)
    
    data = r.json()
    for i in data["data"]:
        await ctx.send(f"Link directo:\n```{i['link']}```\nBBCode(Para foros):\n```[img]{i['link']}[/img]```")
````